# Sketch works on MEGA 2560 timer2, but does not work on timer1

Tags: pwm, frequency, atmega2560

I set the PWM frequency on MEGA 2560 like this:

```
  TCCR2A = 0;           
  TCCR2B = 0;           
  TCNT2  = 0;          

  TCCR2A = _BV(COM2A1)  
           | _BV(COM2B1)  
           | _BV(WGM20);  
     TCCR2B = (TCCR2B & 0b11111000) | 0x02; 

it works good, now I want to use timer1 on PWM and I changed the code like follow but no work:

TCCR1A = 0;           
  TCCR1B = 0;        
  TCNT1  = 0;          

  TCCR1A = _BV(COM1A1)  
           | _BV(COM1B1)  
           | _BV(WGM10);  

  TCCR1B = (TCCR1B & 0b11111000) | 0x02;
```

What's wrong with the changes?

I added 'TOP = ICR1', and when I tested, the ICR1's value effected both the PWM's frequency and duty cycle, how to avoid ICR1 effect dutu cycle?

Comment: what is your question? ..... what does this mean? `but no work` ................ are the two timers interchangeable?

Comment: I don't know much, I just mechanically changed 2 as 1 relatively.

Comment: Thank you jsotola. I'm using a pair RC remote control module to test some thing, when I set Timer2 on MEGA 2560 , the communication is OK. It is no communication when I modified the timer set from timer2 to timer1.